# Corrupted /dev/sda2

Tags: boot, 20.04, initramfs, fsck, busybox

Often while i boot to my system,i am taken to Busybox initramfs screen. I have to do:

`fsck /dev/sda2`

to bring it back to order(several fix options,like **missing inode**,come.I should have kept a note of the errors, maybe I'll do that next time and update here). Some other times, this happens while I am logged in. All filesystems become read-only(**apt update** returns *error*) and again **fsck** has to be called for rescue. This mostly happens after I use Skype, but this may not be correlated. Is my hard drive failing?(SMART status says OK). Or is it something else?

P.S : I have also switched to Ubuntu 20.04 recently,before which this was not happening.

Comment: Do you have Windows installed? Show me the `Disks` app SMART Data window, use multiple screenshots, as that window is scollable. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: @heynnema i use ubuntu 20.04. I have taken a short SMART test with the default disks app. Here is the result: https://www.dropbox.com/s/94d4an0uedcg03k/Screenshot%20from%202020-06-20%2016-21-11.png?dl=0




P.S : One thing i should add, I dont know if it is relevant. My laptop sometimes turns off due to a slight knock on the back panel.

Comment: Do you have Windows installed? Is your disk a SSD or HDD? If SSD, what brand? SMART shows a problem. Is this a desktop or laptop? Show me `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version` and tell me exactly what make/model your computer is.

Comment: @heynnema I dont have windows. My Bios version is A19. My disk is HDD(TOSHIBA MQ01ABD100 (AX0P2D)). My laptop is Dell Inspiron 3558.

Comment: @heynnema 
I am doing a bad block. I would add that the problem definitely happens after using skype. Also,Should I reboot normally after badblock is done?

Comment: Yes, reboot after the bad blocking. Report back with the results of the bad blocking.

Comment: @heynnema I am attaching the result. Also, while the check was nearly complete (99.96%) the errors read 135/0/0.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1noa--ZgrDSB_r1KcH1hbR4n7ttYF6Gq7/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Also now on booting I'm getting this screen of Dell recovery. Following the QR code says the hard disk is malfunctioning.  https://www.dropbox.com/s/576fsbcdnt15tdw/IMG_4949.jpg?dl=0

Comment: As I thought, the HDD has failed. Replace it. Get a SSD if you can afford it.

Comment: @heynnema Thank you for your assistance. In the meantime, is it possible to install ubuntu avoiding the badblocks temporarily? I really need to use my computer .immediately :(

Comment: I would say not. However, if you boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB, and attach a separate external disk, you might be able to backup files that you don't have backed up already. If the BAD BLOCKING completed, then theoretically bad blocks are mapped out, and theoretically you MIGHT be able to reinstall. Do another `fsck` first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your BIOS is current.

If your *"slight knock on the back panel"* occurred while the computer was running, your HDD probably had a minor/major head crash. You have CRC and write errors. You could have HDD problems, or a problem with the SATA drive cable (that might require a re-seat or replace).

It's unclear why it's powering off at this point. There may be other problems.

First we'll check the file system, then we'll bad block the disk.

**fsck**

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB in “Try Ubuntu” mode
- open a `terminal` window by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
- type `sudo fdisk -l`
- identify the /dev/sdXX device name for your "Linux Filesystem"
- type `sudo fsck -f /dev/sda2`, replacing `sdXX` with the number you found earlier
- repeat the `fsck` command if there were errors

**bad block**

Note: do NOT abort a bad block scan!

Note: do NOT bad block a SSD

Note: backup your important files FIRST!

Note: this will take many hours

Note: you may have a pending HDD failure

Boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB in “Try Ubuntu” mode.

In `terminal`...

`sudo fdisk -l` # identify all "Linux Filesystem" partitions

<strike>`sudo e2fsck -fcky /dev/sdXX` # read-only test</strike>

or

`sudo e2fsck -fccky /dev/sda2` # non-destructive read/write test **(recommended)**

The -k is important, because it saves the previous bad block table, and adds any new bad blocks to that table. Without -k, you loose all of the prior bad block information.

The -fccky parameter...

```
   -f    Force checking even if the file system seems clean.

   -c    This option causes e2fsck to use badblocks(8) program to do
         a read-only scan of the device in order to find any bad blocks.
         If any bad blocks are found, they are added to the bad block
         inode to prevent them from being allocated to a file or direc‐
         tory.  If this option is specified twice, then the bad block scan
         will be done using a non-destructive read-write test.

   -k    When combined with the -c option, any existing bad blocks in the
         bad blocks list are preserved, and any new bad blocks found by
         running badblocks(8) will be added to the existing bad blocks
         list.

   -y    Assume an answer of `yes' to all questions; allows e2fsck to be
         used non-interactively. This option may not be specified at the
         same time as the -n or -p options.
```

**Update #1:**

You need to replace the HDD.

Comment: I am doing a bad block. I would add that the problem definitely happens after using skype. Also,Should  I reboot normally after badblock is done?